# 20 year old home with ceiling cracks getting worse

Tags: ceiling, cracks

I have a Town-home that has these ceiling cracks that seem to get worse in the past 5 years. Please see attached. Do you think we need to worry? We got it inspected by a foundation expert 2 years ago(when the opening of the crack was half the current size) and he didn't raise any alarm and said it's common to have foundation settling.
Additionally, garage door seems to be getting stuck recently(right under this crack).
Please let me know your concerns.
-thanks
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be difficult for us to judge better than an expert on site. That said, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: That is a serious crack. I hope your “inspector” has errors and omissions insurance.

Comment: Do you know what's in there??  Is that drywall or concrete?

Comment: I suspect your "expert" was not really an expert.  You need to get a Professional Engineer (i.e. P.E.) who specializes in structural work to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the comments. @JACK, it is drywall with wooden support beam.  From experience, what's the concern if we don't fix? some additional info. The home is sitting on a shared foundation(with atleast 2 others). one home doesn't show any cracks. Not sure about the other one.

-regards

Comment: That's huge.  I'd get this checked again by a reputable company.  You might have a subsidence problem.  Is that a wooden or concrete lintel?

Answer (score 1):

While I do agree with all of the comments above. Yes, it must be addressed immediately. And yes, the foundation may very well be perfectly fine.

However, obvious increasing size and door operation changes are absolutely not normal settling.

It could be from bad framing --- Structure that was meant to sit on a stud or beam wasn't and was only held by nails.

Water Leak --- Roof or plumbing leak could have rotted wood or metal of a joist hanger.

Excessive load --- May be from remodeling that removed structure or didn't consider structure concerning the load above.

Poor support --- Maybe a shim wasn't installed under mis-measured and/or cut framing or a support post wasn't simply tightened up to what it was to support.

Other trades --- Plumber, Electrician or HVAC may have comprimised the structure in completion of their task. Very common and very overlooked.